# Starting on a sketch of unit function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following unit step function:

u2(t)+1-u1(t)

The constant is confusing me, can you help get me started?

Comment: Can you sketch $u_2(t)$?

Comment: Yes, it will be 0 until you get to 2 then the function will turn on from 2 and after.  so you would have a line to 0 then a dark circle on (2,1) and line at y=1

Comment: Okay. When you have both $u_2$ and $u_1$ in the mix, you need to divide the $t$-axis by the points $t=1$ and $t=2$, and evaluate the function within each interval separately (it's constant there).

Comment: ok, I think I got it...thank you :)